# A branching law involving 2-power exterior representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, plethysm

Let $K=SU(n)$.
We take a maximal torus $T$ in $K$ and fixed a simple root system with fundamental weights $\eta_1,\dots,\eta_{n-1}$.
For $\mu$ a dominant weight of $K$, we denote by $(\tau_\mu,V_\mu)$ the irreducible complex representation of $K$ with highest weight $\mu$.
Note that $V_{\eta_2}\simeq \Lambda^2(\mathbb C^n)$.

Let $(\rho,W)$ be the *real* representation of $K$ with highest weight $\eta_2$ in the sense that $W\otimes_\mathbb R\mathbb C\simeq V_{{\eta_2}}\oplus V_{{\eta_2}}^*$.
Since $\rho$ is of complex type, $K$ embeds into $G:=SU(V_{\eta_2})\equiv SU(N)$ with $N=\dim V_{\eta_2} =\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Similarly as with $K$, take a maximal torus of $G$ containing $\rho(T)$ and a simple root system compatible with the previous one and fundamental weights $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_{N-1}$.
Let $\pi_{\lambda}$ denote the irreducible representation of $G$ with highest weight $\lambda$.

(1) Does the representation $\pi_{\omega_2} \circ \rho:K\to GL(V_{\omega_2}) = GL(\Lambda^2(\mathbb C^{N}))$ have fixed point by $K$?

(2) How can I decompose $\pi_{\omega_2} \circ \rho$ in irreducible representations of $K$?

Calculations in Sage suggest that $\pi_{\omega_2} \circ \rho$ is $K$-irreducible for $n\geq3$ (with highest weight $\eta_1+\eta_3$ for $n\geq4$), which immediately provides an answer for (1):
only the element $0$ is fixed by $K$.

Although the question focused in very particular choices of $K$, $\rho$, $G$, $\omega_2$, I am interested on general method for (1) and (2).
How does Sage obtain this branching laws?